# DebuggerStepThrough Attribute - How to also skip child Methods

Tags: c#, .net, system.diagnostics

I've been using the **`System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough`** attribute to skip code when working in Visual Studio Debugger.
However, there are times when I want it to also skip any methods that are called from within the methods I've applied the **`DebuggerStepThrough`** attribute.

Is there a way to do this?
I don't want this to affect all of the methods I've applied this attribute however there are times when I don't want any code that is called/used to open the debugger for all methods called within a method I've applied this attribute.

```
static void main(string[] args)
{
    Method1();
}

[DebuggerStepThrough()]
private static void Method1()
{
    Method2(); 'The Debugger is stopping in Method2 when I am manually stepping through the code
}

private static void Method2()
{
    '... Code I don't care about however debugger is stopping here.
}
```

So the code sample above is an example of what I'm running into.
Is there a way for me to tell Visual Studio to also step over methods called from within `Method1()`?
Currently when I am manually stepping through code in Visual Studio I am finding that I am having to add the **`[DebuggerStepThrough()]`** attribute to all methods called even when they were called from within a method that had the attribute applied.  In this example the debugger is stopping inside `Method2()`.

I'm hoping there is a way that would allow me to NOT have to apply this attribute to ALL of the methods called from the *Parent* method.
Perhaps there's just something easy I'm missing with this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a [DebuggerStepperBoundaryAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepperboundaryattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) to the method that you want to skip while stepping-through.

In the sample code, when the execution stops at the **`Method1()`** call and you step through the code, instead of ending up inside **`Method2`**, the code execution will continue with **`Console.WriteLine("Suddenly here")`** (of course the code in both `Method1` and `Method2` is run):

```
static void main(string[] args)
{
    Method1();
    Console.WriteLine("Suddenly here");
}

[DebuggerStepThrough, DebuggerStepperBoundary]
private static void Method1()
{
    Method2();
}

private static void Method2()
{
    //Skipped
    Console.WriteLine("Skipped but still printing");
}
```