# vb.net Ignore stepping through certain functions when using F5

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

When I use the debugger and F5 to follow along what is currently being called in my app, I have some functions which I don't want the debugger to go through.

These functions are not important to me, and I know what they are doing. Having the debugger step through each line of this function is just taking my time.

How could I make it so that the debugger ignores the function?

Thank you!

Comment: If you are using the old VB6 shortcuts, F8 steps into and Shift+F8 steps over. However in both the old and new shortcuts, F5 executes everything without stopping, except at breakpoints.

Comment: [DebuggerStepThrough Attribute - How to also skip child Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53990683/7444103)

Comment: f8 steps to the  next line shift-F8 runs the sub, skips debug of that routine, and your on the next line. So, shift-F8 should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @Jimi, I found a VB.net solution.

One has to add

```
<DebuggerStepThrough()>
```

over the first line of the function.

For example:

```
<DebuggerStepThrough()>
Public Function StrLen(ByVal uString As String) As Integer

    If (Not uString Is Nothing) AndAlso (Not uString = String.Empty) Then
        Return uString.Length
    Else
        Return 0
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Side note: you can simplify your function slightly with this: `If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(uString) Then`

Comment: Glad to see your problem solved, you can click '✔' to mark it as the accepted answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.